# Try to ExpandProperties in filesMatching in my gradle build

Tags: gradle, groovy, ant, build.gradle, gradlew

I have the following gradle build

./build.gradle

```
defaultTasks 'build'

task build(type: Copy){

    // read the properties from the versions.properties file
    Properties props = new Properties()
    props.load(new FileInputStream("../versions.properties"))
    props.each() { k, v ->
        ant.properties[k] = v
    }

    // copy files and replace placeholders
    from('ansible'){
        filesMatching('**/*.ini') {
            filter(org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ExpandProperties, project: ant.project)
        }
        filesMatching('**/*.yml') {
            println it
            filter(org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ExpandProperties, project: ant.project)
        }
        filesMatching('**/*.xml') {
            println it
            filter(org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ExpandProperties, project: ant.project)
        }
    }

    into 'build/pkg/ansible' 

    includeEmptyDirs = true

}
```

I want to replace all "${variableName}" with the value defined in ../versions.properties for that variable in all the *.xml, *.ini and *.yml files and copy all files to a new folder.

For example:
../versions.properties

```
versionA=1.3
versionB=2.3
```

./ansible/example-file.yml

```
replace this version. => ${versionA}
```

expected output in ./build/pkg/ansible/example-file.yml

```
replace this version. => 1.3
```

The result of the above build is that all files are copied to the right locations, but no property replacement has been made. :-(

Where's my error?

Cheers,
d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually does work as expcected. I missed that the "copy" task of gradle does not overwrite as default.

Specifying the task as follows, solved my problem:

```
task build(type: Copy, overwrite: true){
...
}
```

Cheers,
d.